# Converting strings in octal base into decimal integer in R

Tags: r, decimal, octal

I have a number in octal base in string form (see below for an example):

```
02686a6552f426f08ac0f20ce7dca23e
```

and I need to transform it into a decimal integer using R. I have tried googling the relevant function, but I could only find functions that either convert decimal to octal such as:

```
as.octmode()
```

Or provides conversion between hexadecimal and decimal bases from the fBasics package:

```
.hex.to.dec
```

I have hoped for there to be a function line change.base(string,base_from,base_to), but I have only been able to find strtoi with the following arguments:

```
strtoi("02686a6552f426f08ac0f20ce7dca23e",base=8)
```

which gives me an NA value and the documentation stating "Convert strings to integers according to the given base using", but it doesn't state whether the base argument specifies the base from which we do the transformation or the one into which we transform (I assume the latter since the example poste above doesn't provide retuls)

It seems that php function decoct() gives a result:

```
echo octdec(02686a6552f426f08ac0f20ce7dca23e)
5176
```

But I do not really know php. According to our developers decoct(payment_id) + 3 ) * 7 is the only operation applied to an integer in this case. This is pushed into Google Analytics which provides the result in the example form. I wasn't able to find anything on GA doing this by default.

It would be easy to do the conversion mathematically if I had just the number in octal, but since the format looks like what I assume is some kind of a hash representation of the original number, I am clueless.

I need to run this over hundreds of similar records to compare two data sources so can't really use the php sandbox to do it manually.

Thanks for any help or pointers

Comment: To me it looks more like md5.. So, first you should figure out what this really is. Note that `decoct` in php converts decimal to octal

Comment: This is not an octal number, since it contains digits larger than 7 and even letters. It has all the characteristics of an (enormous) hexadecimal number.

Comment: @Julius I made a mistake typing it up I meand octdect

Comment: @Rhertel I have mentioned it is some kind of a hash representation or encryption, I know octal should only have symbol within 0-7, according to the developer the code that pushes this number is 
decoct(payment_id) + 3 ) * 7 so it needs to be an octal number, only hashed or encrypted in some way shape of form

Answer (score 1):

The hexadecimal number can be converted into a decimal integer with the `Rmpfr` package:

```
library(Rmpfr)
x <- mpfr("02686a6552f426f08ac0f20ce7dca23e", base=16)
#> x
# 1 'mpfr' number of precision  128   bits 
#[1] 3200612827992787429417270296251769406
```

To convert this number into an octal one, the same library can be used:

```
formatMpfr(x,base=8)
#[1] "23206514524572046741053007440634767121076.000"
```